# Laravel blade - get attributes

Tags: laravel, eloquent, attributes, laravel-blade

How can I  do this in my view: $tva = $order->OrderLine->Model->Product->Tva->value ?

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
     <tr>
          <td>{{$order->id}}</td>                                            
          <td>{{$order->statut}}</td>  
          <td>{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($order->created_at)->format('d-m-Y h:i:s')}}</td>
          <?php $prixHT=0 ?>
          @foreach ($order->OrderLine as $line)
                <?php $priceHT += ($line->model->priceHT * $line->quantite) ?>                                                
         @endforeach
    <!-- $tva = $order->OrderLine->Model->Product->Tva->value -->
     <td>{{$prixHT * ($tva/100)}}</td>
```

[orders] 1,n ( ) 1,1 [order_lines] 1,1 ( ) 1,n [models] 1,1 ( ) 1,n [products] 1,1 ( ) 0,n [tvas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign variable inside Blate, you can do

```
<?php $tva = $order->OrderLine->Model->Product->Tva->value; ?>
```

Or

```
{{--*/ $tva = $order->OrderLine->Model->Product->Tva->value /*--}}
```

Comment: But $tva = $order->OrderLine->Model->Product->Tva->value; not work, i' edit my post in 10sec

Comment: Do you have all those relationships in your models ?

Comment: Good, perhaps you should make it as solve and mark my answer. Thanks.